fail to turn on wlan on my laptop
I'm building the environment of CSI tools.
My laptop is Thinkpad X201 and the system is Ubuntu 14.04.
I use the command below:
 rfkill list all
0: phyo: wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes
I cannot use the rfkill unblock allto turn off the hard block.
Besides，when I open the system, it shows"iwlwifi: module has bad taint, not creating trace event".I don't know its meanings and the solution.
If you have solution or other suggestions,you can tell and I am gald to try.
Thank you.

Only fully supported releases of Ubuntu (standard support) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is in extended support and now Ubuntu 14.04 ESM thus only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage and off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/
